# My wordpress site can't handle my scripts with "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I created my site with my own design. My site has some "interactive" functions, like as menu and buttons called actionButton (actionBtn). All of these functions has a js, because it's an toggle interactions.

If you will click on the menu icon, the menu content will be shown, and if you'll click on the close icon when it's opened, you can close it. But this script/function works only if you logged in wordpress.

When I logged out, these scripts not working. I have an error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I would like to ask your help.

My site URL: http://bknmetal.hu

PS.: Sorry about my english.

I've already tried with of these:
- https://blog.templatetoaster.com/fix-jquery-is-not-defined-error/
- I've tried to add/upgrade my jQuery CDN (jquery-migrate also) from https://code.jquery.com/

Thank you so much for your answers/helps in advance.

Comment: Don't be share the username and password of your site.

Comment: Your bknjs script is include at head but jquery is include at body. You need to move your script after jquery.

Comment: @DarknessZX Thanks for your reply. I set back my scripts to the original method what I was wrote before. My scripts in the end of the content inside the body at now, but the "problem" still exists.

Comment: @TribesCreative I still see your script and slick before jquery script. It need to be after jquery script. For example:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="...jquery">
<script type="text/javascript" src="...slick">
<script>
   ...your script
</script>`

Comment: @DarknessZX Oh, that was my own inattention. It is true. Problem was solved. Thanks a lot.